# Unix - use of the different drivers trees?

Tags: c, linux, unix, tree, drivers

#### Context :

My question has a strong assumption : no user can list the tree of drivers.

I Was reading [this (organization of the different drivers in Linux/Unix](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6872?page=0,3).

If a new operating system was created and no user could list the tree of drivers, should such a complicated tree needed ?

My feeling is : no, as far as the kernel is able to find one driver very fast.

Then it could be relevant to just limit ourselves to an array of struct  like so:

```
struct descript_driver {

    /* the usual struct with the functions 
     * pointers(.open = blah, .mmap = blah and so on). 
     */
    struct actions act;

    char * driver_name;
    char * vendor_name;  

    int vendorid; 
    int class_type; // GRAPHIC, NETWORK, CAMERA (#define or enum)...
    int major_id;
    int minor_id;
};

/* 256 is just an example. It could be more, or less. 
 * There are up to 256 majors but potentially a lot of minors. 
 * And each one has its index.
 * Addressing is O(1).
 */
struct descript_driver array_of_drivers[256];
```

And having the drivers/kernel remembering its index only to flow in the array.

Interrupts would still take the major number.
And thanks to the minor number, it is still easy to find the right function to call in O(1).

Is there something wrong in my thought ? This is an important point to polish my project.

Thanks

Comment: Many physical device layouts are laid out in trees. For example USB drives connected to USB hubs. PCIe video cards connected to PCIe switches.

Comment: Yes, they would use the right hub through their respective class in my case. They would be laid out too. But they would be fast to address. I may have missed something in your comment, an I apologize about it Bill.

Comment: I mean that a kernel's device layout often reflects the physical layout of the devices. We can always have `O(1)` access to an object through it's pointer (which isn't much larger than your index) and we often want to have very quick access to a device's children and it's parent. Which is a tree.

Comment: Why do we need the device child and parent ? In the end, it adds intelligence && computation; and I am not sure why it would be needed. A simple index would do it. The code it smart already, the kernel should just execute.

Comment: And the current O(1) is slow because of cache misses.